# Correct way of waiting for async result in Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, async-await, vuex

I wonder where to put in lifecycle waiting for the promise result. Runnable sample is there: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-surf-migyw. I create a `Promise` in `created()` and wait for the result in `async mounted()`. Is this right and optimal usage of Vue component lifecycle?

PS I do not want to store the result as a mutation in the store because I can call this method multiple times. Therefore I return the `Promise`. It downloads user detail from a REST endpoint.

store.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  actions: {
    FETCH_PROFILE: async context => {
      const profile = { name: "Leos" };
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
          resolve(profile);
        }, 2000);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

component.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <p>Name = {{this.userProfile.name}}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data: () => ({
    userProfile: null,
    profilePromise: null
  }),
  created() {
    this.profilePromise = this.$store.dispatch("FETCH_PROFILE");
    console.log(`my profile: ${this.userProfile}`);
  },
  async mounted() {
    const response = await this.profilePromise;
    console.log(response);
    this.userProfile = response;
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: It's `const response = await this.$store.dispatch("FETCH_PROFILE")`. No need for `created`.

Comment: Unless you have some extraordinarily compelling reason to break this up into using both `created` and `mounted`, it would make more sense to do it all in `async created`.  (`mounted` is generally for DOM manipulation.)  Just  `const response = await this.$store.dispatch("FETCH_PROFILE");  this.userProfile = response`

Comment: I thought that starting it earlier may save some milliseconds

Comment: No, if anything it should be equal speed both ways, just the time taken to interpret the code.  (We are probably talking about fractions of a nanosecond rather than milliseconds anyway).  You don't have to worry that this will postpone the mount because async calls are non-blocking.

Comment: and is the async/wait in mount the correct way of waiting for the result?

Comment: Yes, but use `created`.  I'll post an answer with the exact syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have some extraordinarily compelling reason to break this up into using both `created` and `mounted`, it would make more sense to do it all in `created`.  You don't have to worry that this will postpone the mount because async calls are non-blocking.  Use `created` rather than `mounted`, which is generally for DOM manipulation or DOM sensitive operations.

```
async created() {
  const response = await this.$store.dispatch("FETCH_PROFILE");
  this.userProfile = response;
}
```

Comment: AFAIK the problem with lifecycle hooks Vue is similar to React, i.e. it's SSR. Async side effects aren't supposed to be executed on server side, but they will if they are made in `created`. Also, `async` `created` gives false impression that it will finish before `mounted`, which isn't true, I've seen several questions that shared this misconception.

Comment: @EstusFlask - He hasn't mentioned SSR/Nuxt and I don't know React so I can't comment on that comparison.  Nuxt has other ways of doing things, too (see [`asyncData`](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data/)).  As far as that false impression, I don't see it and I wouldn't suggest micro-optimizing code for an edge misunderstanding, especially considering that it will make his app slower and he is already talking about optimizing for milliseconds.  That said, mounted will work and it's not "wrong", but I prefer a clearer encapsulation and I think most Vue documentation would suggest the same.

Comment: Real challenge would be to find out where AWS lambda spends so much time ..